# Failed to install apoc in docker neo4j

Tags: docker, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have running neo4j instance in production and development environments. It is hosted on VM using docker. Now I want to use apoc.

I wrote this Dockerfile.

```
FROM neo4j:5.1.0-community

ENV APOC_VERSION=5.1.0

ENV apoc.export.file.enabled=true
ENV apoc.import.file.enabled=true
ENV apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=true

ADD https://github.com/neo4j/apoc/releases/download/${APOC_VERSION}/apoc-${APOC_VERSION}-core.jar /plugins/
```

Which seems fine according to the documentation. However when trying to bring up I got this error:

```
2023-04-26 18:54:34.915+0000 INFO  Starting...
2023-04-26 18:54:35.881+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{ac8140db} (ac8140db-4060-498a-818d-b7beaa3b826e)
2023-04-26 18:54:37.464+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 5.1.0 ========
2023-04-26 18:54:41.802+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on 0.0.0.0:7474.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /data/databases
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:255) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:193) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:164) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:85) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:30) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry@31db34da' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Some jar procedure files (apoc-5.1.0-core.jar) are invalid, see log for details.".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:370) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:246) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Some jar procedure files (apoc-5.1.0-core.jar) are invalid, see log for details.
        at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:74) ~[neo4j-procedure-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.start(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:338) ~[neo4j-procedure-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:353) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:246) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        ... 5 more
2023-04-26 18:54:41.805+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2023-04-26 18:54:41.806+0000 INFO  Stopped.
```

Comment: In the error message: `Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry@31db34da' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Some jar procedure files (apoc-5.1.0-core.jar) are invalid, see log for details` is showing `jar file for APOC is invalid`. Check whether jar file exists in the `/plugins/directory` of the `Neo4j container`. If it doesn't exist then rebuild the docker image. If file exist then possibly file is corrupted in this case try to redownload the file

Comment: There is this file. It is downloaded from official page and file seems just fine. Dont know what else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! It's problem with permissions. In documentations it is stated to mount this file from your host machine. Which by default gives you this permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000
```

hovewer when you add the file, permissions are:

```
-rw------- 1 root root
```

So everything you need to do. Is to add:

```
RUN chmod a+r /plugins/apoc-${APOC_VERSION}-core.jar
```

at the end of your file